# OperationalError at /admin/login/ attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: python, django, sqlite, centos, selinux

I have deployed my Django application in the CENTOS 7, it up and running , all select operation from data base is working fine and now i am unable to login to admin page and also unable to perform any write operations on the Data base , i am using defaut db.sqlite3 as a my data base,

Please i have SELinux is enabled, which we need for other security policies, please help, i have followed all other Stack-overflow answers given chown apache:apache permissions to project directory also for db.sqlite3,

Also i have used enabled http_unified as 1 also, but not working

PFB below errors

```
attempt to write a readonly database
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://192.168.225.45/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
attempt to write a readonly database
Exception Location: /home/www/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 413, in execute
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.6.9

    
    ignored_wrapper_args    
(False,
 {'connection': <django.db.backends.sqlite3.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7fd9f6760278>,
  'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x7fd9f7f69e48>})
params  
['Sunag', 12331, 'M']
self    
<django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x7fd9f7f69e48>
sql 
('INSERT INTO "testapp_candidatemodel" ("name", "rollno", "shirt_size") VALUES '
 '(%s, %s, %s)')
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l db.sqlite3` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Has more to do with making IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool as a user in IIS to give it full control that the SQL Database is sitting in..... seemed to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

you need to do this:

```
sudo chmod 777 db.sqlite
```

it should work.